# Почему не работает проверка на ввод в input?

Tags: javascript

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if (document.querySelector(".input").value.length >= 1) {
        document.querySelector(".blockk").style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Washington, D.C.">
<span class="blockk">Required</span>
```

Comment: Потому, что у Вас `value=''` по умолчанию, а обработчик на ввод отсутствует.

Answer (score 0):

потому что `placeholder` показывает некоторый текст, когда в поле ввода ничего нет

у вас в поле ввода ничего нет, поэтому показывается `Washington, D.C.`, но при этом `.value.length` равно `0`, поскольку... в поле ввода ничего нет :)

если по умолчанию сделать некоторое заполнение поля ввода, то все будет работать корректно

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if (document.querySelector(".input").value.length >= 1) {
        document.querySelector(".blockk").style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Washington, D.C." value = "XXX">
<span class="blockk">Required</span>
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы при вводе текста исчезал блок, то отслеживать надо уже другие события

```js
document.querySelector(".input").addEventListener('input', function() {
  document.querySelector(".blockk").style.display = (document.querySelector(".input").value.length > 0) ? 'none' : 'inline-block'; 
});
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Washington, D.C.">
<span class="blockk">Required</span>
```

Comment: oninput отлично справится с этой задачей?

Comment: вам надо чтобы когда вводился текст блок исчезал, а когда стирался текст - блок появлялся заново?

Comment: да, пока что я сделал чтобы он просто исчезал

Comment: добавил в свой ответ требуемый код - дальше можете его наворачивать